# python: image to 2-dimensional list

Tags: python

Is there a python lib that could make a 2-dimensional list of (R,G,B) data out of an image file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm). It has the ability to be directly converted to a 2 by 2 by 3 [numpy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
im = Image.open( filename )
data = numpy.asarray( im )
```

Answer (score 3):

Or ImageMagick at http://wiki.python.org/moin/ImageMagick